# Double Dimension Arrays Java

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array

My code works perfectly fine though i don't know how to print the number of the row before the word "row". It should be Row 1, Row 2, and so on. Any clues on how to do it? And also a clue to store these strings in a simpler way. Thank youuu :)

```
System.out.println("\t A \t B \t C \t D \t E \t F");
String [][] TwoDim = new String[13][6];
TwoDim[0][0] = "*";
TwoDim[0][1] = "*";
TwoDim[0][2] = "X";
TwoDim[0][3] = "*";
TwoDim[0][4] = "X";
TwoDim[0][5] = "X";

TwoDim[1][0] = "*";
TwoDim[1][1] = "X";
TwoDim[1][2] = "*";
TwoDim[1][3] = "X";
TwoDim[1][4] = "*";
TwoDim[1][5] = "X";

TwoDim[2][0] = "*";
TwoDim[2][1] = "*";
TwoDim[2][2] = "X";
TwoDim[2][3] = "X";
TwoDim[2][4] = "*";
TwoDim[2][5] = "X";

TwoDim[3][0] = "X";
TwoDim[3][1] = "*";
TwoDim[3][2] = "X";
TwoDim[3][3] = "*";
TwoDim[3][4] = "X";
TwoDim[3][5] = "X";

TwoDim[4][0] = "*";
TwoDim[4][1] = "X";
TwoDim[4][2] = "*";
TwoDim[4][3] = "X";
TwoDim[4][4] = "*";
TwoDim[4][5] = "*";

TwoDim[5][0] = "*";
TwoDim[5][1] = "X";
TwoDim[5][2] = "*";
TwoDim[5][3] = "*";
TwoDim[5][4] = "*";
TwoDim[5][5] = "X";

TwoDim[6][0] = "X";
TwoDim[6][1] = "*";
TwoDim[6][2] = "*";
TwoDim[6][3] = "*";
TwoDim[6][4] = "X";
TwoDim[6][5] = "X";

TwoDim[7][0] = "*";
TwoDim[7][1] = "X";
TwoDim[7][2] = "*";
TwoDim[7][3] = "X";
TwoDim[7][4] = "X";
TwoDim[7][5] = "*";

TwoDim[8][0] = "X";
TwoDim[8][1] = "*";
TwoDim[8][2] = "X";
TwoDim[8][3] = "X";
TwoDim[8][4] = "*";
TwoDim[8][5] = "X";

TwoDim[9][0] = "*";
TwoDim[9][1] = "X";
TwoDim[9][2] = "*";
TwoDim[9][3] = "X";
TwoDim[9][4] = "X";
TwoDim[9][5] = "X";

TwoDim[10][0] = "*";
TwoDim[10][1] = "*";
TwoDim[10][2] = "X";
TwoDim[10][3] = "*";
TwoDim[10][4] = "X";
TwoDim[10][5] = "*";

TwoDim[11][0] = "*";
TwoDim[11][1] = "*";
TwoDim[11][2] = "X";
TwoDim[11][3] = "X";
TwoDim[11][4] = "*";
TwoDim[11][5] = "X";

TwoDim[12][0] = "*";
TwoDim[12][1] = "*";
TwoDim[12][2] = "*";
TwoDim[12][3] = "*";
TwoDim[12][4] = "X";
TwoDim[12][5] = "*";

for(int i = 0; i<13; i++){
    System.out.print("Row \t");
    for(int j = 0; j <6; j++){
        System.out.print(TwoDim[i][j] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: The output is like a table with rows and columns @ambigram_maker

Comment: Next time, please reduce your code to say a `3x5` matrix, as that would be enough to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Change your line

```
System.out.print("Row \t");
```

to something like this:

```
System.out.print("Row " + (i + 1) + "\t");
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `i`is your row number, starting from `0`, so just write (assuming you want to start at `1`):

```
for(int i = 0; i<13; i++){
    System.out.print("Row \t"+(i+1)+" ");
    for(int j = 0; j <6; j++){
        System.out.print(TwoDim[i][j] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.print("Row " + i +  "\t");
```

`i` is the first index in your array, and thus corresponds to the row. If you want to make is `1` based rather than a `0` based index, output `i + 1` each time.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the hardcoded value of row and column,Use below code:

```
    for(int i = 0; i<TwoDim.length; i++){   // Iterate to row count

        System.out.print("Row-"+(i+1)+"\t"); // Change i to i+1

            for(int j = 0; j <TwoDim[i].length; j++){  // Iterate the column count
                System.out.print(TwoDim[i][j] + "\t");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.out.print("Row \t"+i);
```

In case your indexing starts from 1

```
 System.out.print("Row \t"+(i+1));
```

Comment: That will put the number after a tab character. Also, it will start counting at 0 while it should start with 1.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried:

```
for(int i = 0; i<13; i++){
   System.out.print("Row \t " + i);
   for(int j =0; j < 6; j++ {
       ...
   }
}
```

Comment: That will put the number after a tab character. Also, it will start counting at 0 while it should start with 1.